# HiveQL TimeStamp Error

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the hiveQL query shown below in which I am trying to get the timestamp values for the target_end_date and date fields with the day value in each set to 1.

My timestamp values are coming out way off like 2013-07-10 coming out as 1970-01-01, any tips on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

`select
    to_date(target_end_date) as target_end_date,
    to_date(date) as date,
    timestamp(concat(year(target_end_date),'-',month(target_end_date),'-1')),
    timestamp(concat(year(date),'-',month(date),'-1'))
from
    pns_serial_renewal_vw`

Comment: Try using `unix_timestamp()`. As the doc says, you need to pass `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format date string to this function. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: Thanks, unix_timestamp did the trick!

Comment: Making this comment as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `unix_timestamp()`. As the doc says, you need to pass `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format date string to this function.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions